# Select sublists that contain $n$ odd numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of sublists, let's say

`Subsets[Range[15], {5}]`

I need to select only those of them, that contain 3 odd and 2 even numbers, e.g. `{{1,4,5,7,8},{2,7,9,10,11},{...}}`

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = Subsets[Range[15], {5}];
Pick[lst, Count[#, _?EvenQ] & /@ lst, 2]

%  // Length
```

> 1176

or

```
Pick[lst, Dot[Mod[lst, 2] , ConstantArray[1, 5]], 3] (* or *)
Pick[lst, Total[Mod[lst, 2], {2}], 3]
% // Length
```

> > 1176

Comment: You can use `Total /@ Mod[lst, 2]` instead of `Dot[Mod[lst, 2] , ConstantArray[1, 5]]`

Comment: Thank uou @Okkes. I had  `Total [ Mod[lst, 2], {2}]` previously; Thinking it would be faster i changed it to the `Dot` version.

Answer (score 1):

If the sublists must be ordered:

```
Union @@@ Tuples[{Subsets[Range[1, 15, 2], {3}], Subsets[Range[2, 15, 2], {2}]}]
```

Otherwise:

```
Flatten[Tuples[{Subsets[Range[1, 15, 2], {3}], 
                Subsets[Range[2, 15, 2], {2}]}], {{1}, {2, 3}}]
```

where `Flatten` could alternatively be replaced by
`ArrayReshape[#, {Binomial[Ceiling[15/2], 3] Binomial[Floor[15/2], 2], 3 + 2}] &`

Answer (score 1):

```
Union @@@Join @@ Outer[List, Subsets[Range[2, 15, 2], {2}],Subsets[Range[1, 17, 2], {3}], 1]
```